# Reports on Drupal Usage

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

I'm benchmarking some CMS's for future use. 
I would like to know if with Drupal it's possible to have (extensions or api's) reports of back office usage.

Examples:

1. Users that don't create/update content for more than X days?
2. Content Areas that don't have new content for more than X days?
3. Number of contents waiting approval?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several contributed modules to Drupal that shows statistics for the site, take a look at the statistics category: http://drupal.org/project/statistics

For example, there is a module to display user statistics: http://drupal.org/project/user_stats

The better option is to build a custom module that search the database for the statistics that you need.